# Need help architecting Redux Application (reducing the number of actions required)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am new to redux am and currently in the design phase of my application. I am hoping for someone to tell me wether or not my proposed approach is good (or even valid for that matter) or if there is a better way to do what I am trying to do.

The main problem is that I have 
an application that has many objects which have identical structure. For each of these objects I will 
want to be able to preform updates. It would be nice if I could avoid having to write an action for each
update and instead could right a more general update.

Here is an example of what my state will look like

```
initialState = {
   commonPumpItems:      
        [
            basalRate: {units: ml/hr, activeValue: 125.0, minValue: 3, maxValue: 4}, 
            doseVolume: {units: ml/hr, activeValue: 125.0, minValue:3, maxValue: 4},
            doseRate: {units: ml/hr, activeValue: 135.9, minValue: 5, maxValue: 10},
            ...(about 10 more of these)
        ],
    kvoRate: {status: true, minValue: 0, maxValue: 1}
}
```

commonPumpItems are objects which have units, activeValue, minValue, maxValue.
I want to avoid having to write a wall of actions such as

```
updateBasalRateValue()
updatedoseVolumeValue()
updatedoseRateValue()
updateBasalRateUnits()
etc
```

how could I structure my action creators and reducer so I just have some general action such as

```
updateCommonPumpItem(name, propertyToUpdate, newValue)
```

which could then be called as such

```
updateCommonPumpItem(basalRate, units, ml)
```

My idea is to have something like this

```
def updateCommonPumpItem(name, propToUpdate, newValue){
    return {type: "update", name, propToUpdate, newValue}
}



Then in Reducer.js have something like this

function reducer(state = initialState, action){
     switch (action.type){

           case update: 
               state.commonPumpItems.map( (pumpObject) => {
                     if (pumpObject.name === action.name){
                        return Object.assign{{}, pumpObject, {action.propToUpdate: action.newValue}
                     }
                     else{
                        return pumpObject
                         }
           ..... bunch of other stuff
```

Comment: All actions are are objects. How they're created is entirely up to you--just write a function.

Comment: @DaveNewton updated post with a more concrete example of what I had in mind. does it make sense for me to store the commonPumpItems in this way and then each time i want to do an update have to loop through them just to find the one i want to update? Is there a better approach

Comment: This is what action creators are for. You'd pass in the object and things like that, and say what sort of object it is, the action creator would then act like a factory, returning a function (or action) to match what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I realized there is no need to make things so complicated. Instead of storing `commonPumpItems` in an Array I can just store them as properties in my object. This is a better approach IMO because it eliminates the need to search for the particular item in my reducer.